# FFmpeg:A General error in an external library occurred when using FFmpeg6.1's avcodec_send_frame

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have the same code that can successfully push streams (rtmp) in the environment, but in the Android environment, I fail with an error message. The error message method is avcodec_send_frame in ffmpeg6.1. By the way, I compiled the FFmpeg library on Android myself, and I downloaded the official package for Win11. I will provide the code for Android and Win11 below.

android :

```
static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt,

                   AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx) {
    int ret;

    /* send the frame to the encoder */
    if (frame)
        LOGE2("Send frame %ld\n", frame->pts);

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char errbuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
        LOGE2("Error sending a frame for encoding ,%s\n", errbuf);
//        exit(1);
        return;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Write packet (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts);
        /*    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt);
            if (ret < 0) {
                LOGE2("write frame err=%s", av_err2str(ret));
                break;
            }*/
//        printf("Write packet %3"PRId64" (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        av_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt); // Write the packet to the RTMP stream
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

PUSHER_FUNC(int, testPush, jstring yuvPath, jstring outputPath) {
    const char *yvu_path = env->GetStringUTFChars(yuvPath, JNI_FALSE);
    const char *output_path = env->GetStringUTFChars(outputPath, JNI_FALSE);
    const char *rtmp_url = output_path;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;
    AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx;
    int ret = 0;
    AVStream *outStream;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    int i, x, y;
    avformat_network_init();

    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);
    if (!codec) {
        LOGE2("JNI Error finding H.264 encoder");
        return -1;
    }
    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecContext) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Allocate the output context */
    outFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!outFormatCtx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        return -1;
    }

    /* Open the RTMP output */
    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mpegts", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
    if (!ofmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find output format\n");
        return -1;
    }
    outFormatCtx->oformat = ofmt;
    outFormatCtx->url = av_strdup(rtmp_url);
    /* Add a video stream */
    outStream = avformat_new_stream(outFormatCtx, codec);
    if (!outStream) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        return -1;
    }
    outStream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    outStream->codecpar->codec_id = codec->id;
    outStream->codecpar->width = 352;
    outStream->codecpar->height = 288;

    /* Set the output URL */
    av_dict_set(&outFormatCtx->metadata, "url", rtmp_url, 0);

    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        return -1;

    /* ... (rest of the setup code) ... */
/* put sample parameters */
    codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    codecContext->width = 352;
    codecContext->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    codecContext->time_base = (AVRational) {1, 25};
    codecContext->framerate = (AVRational) {25, 1};

    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    codecContext->gop_size = 10;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        LOGE2("JNI Error opening codec eer%s", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, outStream->codecpar);

    if (avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output\n");
        return ret;
    }
    /* Write the header */
    if (avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output\n");
        return ret;
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        return -1;
    }
    frame->format = codecContext->pix_fmt;
    frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame->format = 0;
    frame->width = codecContext->width;
    frame->height = codecContext->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data ,%s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        return ret;
    }

    /*  FILE *yuv_file = fopen(yvu_path, "rb");
      if (yuv_file == NULL) {
          LOGE2("cannot open h264 file");
          return -1;
      }*/

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for (i = 0; i < 25000; i++) {
//    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
//        fflush(stdout);

        /* make sure the frame data is writable */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height / 2; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width / 2; x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        encode(codecContext, frame, pkt, outFormatCtx);
    }

//    fclose(yuv_file);

    /* flush the encoder */
    encode(codecContext, NULL, pkt, outFormatCtx);

    /* Write the trailer */
    av_write_trailer(outFormatCtx);

    /* Close the output */
    avformat_free_context(outFormatCtx);

    avcodec_free_context(&codecContext);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
}
```

win11：

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>

static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt,
                   AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx) {
    int ret;

    /* send the frame to the encoder */
    if (frame)
        printf("Send frame %3"PRId64"\n", frame->pts);

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        char errbuf[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for encoding ,%s\n", errbuf);
        exit(1);
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Write packet %3"PRId64" (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        av_write_frame(outFormatCtx, pkt); // Write the packet to the RTMP stream
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_DEBUG);
    const char *rtmp_url, *codec_name;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *codecContext = NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y;
    AVFormatContext *outFormatCtx;
    AVStream *st;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = {0, 0, 1, 0xb7};

    if (argc <= 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <rtmp url> <codec name>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    rtmp_url = argv[1];
    codec_name = argv[2];
    avformat_network_init();
    /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_VP9);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AV1);
//    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H265);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name);
        exit(1);
    }
    codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!codecContext) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Allocate the output context */
    outFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!outFormatCtx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate output context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Open the RTMP output */
    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("MKV", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("rtmp", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mpegts", NULL, NULL);
//    const AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("mp4", NULL, NULL);
    if (!ofmt) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find output format\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    outFormatCtx->oformat = ofmt;
    outFormatCtx->url = av_strdup(rtmp_url);
    /* Add a video stream */
    st = avformat_new_stream(outFormatCtx, codec);
    if (!st) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate stream\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    st->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    st->codecpar->codec_id = codec->id;
    st->codecpar->width = 352;
    st->codecpar->height = 288;
//    st->codecpar = c;
//    st->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    // Set video stream parameters
//    st->codecpar->framerate = (AVRational){25, 1};

    /* Set the output URL */
    av_dict_set(&outFormatCtx->metadata, "url", rtmp_url, 0);


    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);

    /* ... (rest of the setup code) ... */
/* put sample parameters */
    codecContext->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    codecContext->width = 352;
    codecContext->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    codecContext->time_base = (AVRational) {1, 25};
    codecContext->framerate = (AVRational) {25, 1};

    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    codecContext->gop_size = 10;
    codecContext->max_b_frames = 1;
    codecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    ret = avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(codecContext, st->codecpar);

    if (avio_open(&outFormatCtx->pb, rtmp_url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Write the header */
    if (avformat_write_header(outFormatCtx, NULL) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred when opening output\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
//    frame->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    frame->format = 0;
    frame->width = codecContext->width;
    frame->height = codecContext->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data ,%s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode 1 second of video */
    for (i = 0; i < 2500; i++) {
        /* ... (rest of the encoding loop) ... */
        fflush(stdout);

        /* make sure the frame data is writable */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for (y = 0; y < codecContext->height / 2; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < codecContext->width / 2; x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        encode(codecContext, frame, pkt, outFormatCtx);
    }

    /* flush the encoder */
    encode(codecContext, NULL, pkt, outFormatCtx);

    /* Write the trailer */
    av_write_trailer(outFormatCtx);

    /* Close the output */
    avformat_free_context(outFormatCtx);

    avcodec_free_context(&codecContext);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);

    return 0;
}
```

I suspect it's an issue with the ffmpeg library I compiled, so I searched for a step to compile ffmpeg on GitHub, but the package it compiled still has the same problem. I don't know what to do now.

Comment: Since you compiled ffmpeg yourself, this is a good opportunity to attach a debugger to your program and step inside the call to avcodec_send_frame. You will find which checks failed exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem to prevent others from encountering the same problem as me. Let me explain it here. The reason why I prefer Win11 to run on Android is because I am using the dynamic library FFmpeg 5.1.2 on Win11, and the FFmpeg library I compiled myself is 6.1, so one of them can run normally while the other cannot. Secondly, the reason for this error on Android is because one of my parameters was set incorrectly. I just need to add a parameter.
`outStream->codecpar->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;`
After adding the above parameter, it will be ready on Android FFmpeg6.1.